# Subaru Forester XT 2002 driver power window malfunctioning

Tags: electrical, subaru, power-windows, forester

My driver side power window does not go down automatically but will go down if you keep the switch depressed. On the other hand the up function only work by continuously pulling and releasing the switch. what might be the cause of this?

The problem is definitely not the motor, since I've already repaired it and the window works perfectly up and and down when operated with direct current by passing the switch. The switch is also new but I know there's a possibility it's defective. Awaiting another switch to try. I will post results.

Comment: Sounds like the switch is bad.

Answer (score 3):

This is a weak point in Subarus.

I have had a Forester non-turbo 2005 for a few years and I have found that, on occasion, the driver-side power window simply fails to operate. But after drawing from a bucket of patience and then trying sometime later, it will work OK. It now seems to have come good and I haven't seen the problem for a number of months. So the problem is obviously some sort of poor electrical connection/grounding to the motor. Although your symptoms are slightly different, I would expect that a motor failure would stop the window from working at all.

As my drivers-side is RHS but your's is presumably LHS, this may be wear-related or it may simply be that we use the drivers-side a lot more and thus notice it there.

I have also purchased a 2006 Impreza recently as a project car and have found that the drivers side window does not operate but all the others are good. When I open it up to fix it, I'll add to this post.

Comment: You have the fun of a rotten window motor too ;) Don't believe the videos on youtube that tell you it's a horrific job that involves taking the glass out, there is a much easier method - post up a new question and I'll explain it ;)

Comment: http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/21365/what-is-the-simplest-way-to-replace-a-subaru-front-power-window-motor

Answer (score 2):

You might be lucky and find that it's only the switch that is bad - that's an easy fix as the switches simply plug in. If it's not that, then it's probably the motor going rotten, as per timbo's car...