# Window motor replacement 2001 Subaru Outback

Tags: subaru, power-windows, outback

How do I replace a right front power window motor on my 2001 Subaru Outback?

Comment: iirc this is one were you can leave the regulator in place. it's been a while but i think you can drill 3 holes in the door frame and pull the bolts for the motor.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the simplest way to replace a Subaru front power window motor?](http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/21365/what-is-the-simplest-way-to-replace-a-subaru-front-power-window-motor)